# Filter not working with array without properties

Tags: javascript

I have an array called `one` which contains a list of objects with properties:

```
[
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]
```

then I have another array called `two` which contains a list of id references:

```
["1", "8"]
```

I want remove from the array `one` the items which have the same id of array `two`, so I did:

```
result = one.filter(function (el) {
   return two.find(item => item == el.id) < 0;
});
```

this return an empty array, but should return:

```
[
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]
```

Comment: When `.find()` does not find something, it returns `undefined`, not a negative number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = one.filter(function (el) {
   return two.find(item => item == el.id) < 0;
});
```

If the element is not found, then `two.find` will return undefined. `undefined < 0` resolves to false, and so that element is not included.

Perhaps you meant to use `findIndex` instead of `find`. In that case, a missing element will result in a -1.

```js
const one = [
  { id: "1"},
  { id: "2"},
  { id: "3"}
]

const two = ["1", "8"]

const result = one.filter(function (el) {
  return two.findIndex(item => item == el.id) < 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you need a faster version ...

```
 const result = one.filter((s => el => !s.has(el.id))(new Set(two)));
```

That's O(n) instead of O(n * m)

Answer (score 2):

You could exclude the objects which `id` is in the unwanted array.

```js
var data = [{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" }],
    unwanted = ["1", "8"],
    filtered = data.filter(({ id }) => !unwanted.includes(id));
   
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = one.filter(function (el) {
   return (two.indexOf(el.id) == -1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns `undefined` if an item is not found.

So remove the numeric comparison and prefix it with a NOT (!) operator.

```js
const one = [
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]

const two = ["1", "8"]

const result = one.filter(function (el) {
   return !two.find(item => item == el.id)
})

console.log(result)
```

However, I'd use [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which is a little more terse.

```js
const one = [
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]

const two = ["1", "8"]

const result = one.filter(item => !two.includes(item.id))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.indexOf()` instead. If it returns -1 , it means the element doesnt exist in the array

```js
var one = [
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]
var two = ["1", "8"]

var result = one.filter(function (el) {
   return two.indexOf(el.id) === -1;
});
console.log(result)
```